# Do we have to migrate our Visual C++ project to Visual Studio 2015 to work on window 10

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

We have a bunch of COM ATL 3.0 projects all in a solution, which were originally built on Visual C++ 6.0, we have migrated this to VS2010 a year back.

We are planning to move to window 10, this will be our dev PC from next year, my question, is it mandatory for us to move VS2015, can we still compile and build our projects on VS2010.

Thank you for looking into this

Comment: That is not mandatory at all.  Merely wise, 6 years are a lot of dog lives in modern C++.  Don't make that same mistake again.  Erm, okay, it is mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary. Visual Studio 2010 runs on Windows 10.

However, updating a C++ project from Visual Studio 2010 to 2015 is fairly trivial - and certainly much easier than from Visual C++ 6.0.

If there are any problems, you can set the platform toolset to Visual Studio 2010 and compile in Visual Studio 2015. (But this might require you to install VS 2010 as well. I'm not sure.)